# Is there a way to only load javascript based on the authenticated or anonymous user?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, page-layout

We have several page layouts that are calling a javascript file and we are trying to improve our page speeds and we figured we only need to call this js file if the user is logged in. Otherwise for anonymous users, we don't need to load it.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, inside the .aspx files for the layout, use the Security Trimmed Control:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx

Specifically you'd probably do something like this:

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl1" AuthenticationRestrictions="AuthenticatedUsersOnly" runat="server">
    <script src="JavaScriptForAuthenticatedUsersOnly.js"></script>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```